# Is John Walker a super soldier in Falcon and the Winter Soldier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

John Walker is introduced as the new Captain America at the end of the first episode of *The Falcon and the Winter Soldier*. He is shown to be extremely capable, athletic and skilled with the shield.

But is he a super soldier and if so, what is the source of his enhancement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the beginning of the miniseries, [John Walker](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/U.S._Agent#Military_Career) is merely a highly trained and decorated soldier.

> Having graduated from the United States Military Academy in 2010, Walker went on to have a successful career in the United States Army, performing numerous acts of valor. He became the first person in American history to receive three Medals of Honor and led RS One missions in counter-terrorism and hostage rescue.

In Episode 4, *[The Whole World is Watching](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Whole_World_Is_Watching)*, in the wake of being defeated by Ayo of the Dora Milaje, nominally an unenhanced combatant, he takes a confiscated sample of the serum, which indeed induces greater strength, speed, and durability, but may have also contributed to his anger issues (as per the general theme that the serum amplifies the inherent nature of person, good and bad) and the incident that led to his downfall.

> As a horde of Flag Smashers attacks the three, Hoskins frees himself from his restraints and rejoins his allies, only to be accidentally killed when Morgenthau violently caves his chest inward with her fist, sending him flying into a pillar. Attempting to flee with his teammates, Nico is hunted down by a vengeful Walker, who brutally murders him with the shield, to the horror of onlookers. Looking up, Walker soon realizes that he is being recorded, the entirety of Earth now bearing witness to his actions.

Comment: Details largely lifted from https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/U.S._Agent#Taking_the_Serum and related articles.

Comment: I suppose it's worth asking if this would put him on the same level with the original Cap (attitude issues aside).  One shot in the arm isn't quite the same as the treatment Cap (or Bucky, or the *What If?* version of Peggy Carter) got, being put into some sort of pressure chamber and injected all over their bodies.

Comment: {nods} Or perhaps comparing him to Isaiah Bradley, who also got some version of the treatment. Although, honestly, enough power origins in the MCU have been attributed to *some* version of the serum (The Hulk, for example) that it gets tricky to really compare them, especially since most were recreated from scant samples.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Steve Rogers and Peggy got zapped with Vita Rays _in addition to the serum_ which iirc we haven't seen anyone else in the MCU receive. https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Vita_Radiation